# how to maintain imagecache in pressflow with load balancer?

Tags: 6, media

I am planning to make load-balancer for my website, it is pressflow 6.2.
the question is: how can i maintain imagecache in the two servers?!!
i need something other than NFS. since NFS will cause overload and will break the website in case that the server that has the images is down!!
**EDIT**
is it possible to have a dedicated server for images using imagecache (if so, how?)
any idea is highly appreciated